# How to dynamically add data values to generated HTML - Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-accountdetailed',
  templateUrl: './accountdetailed.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accountdetailed.page.scss'],
})
export class AccountdetailedPage implements OnInit {

  protected itemId = '';

  public item = {
    email: 'email-1@hotmail.co.uk',
    joinDate: '22-11-2022',
    firstName: 'Angular',
    lastName: 'Patel'
  };

  constructor(
    protected route: ActivatedRoute,
    protected userParamService: UserParametersService,
    protected authService: AuthenticationService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    
    switch (this.itemId) {
      case 'yourDetails':
        this.yourDetailsHtml();
    }
  }


  protected yourDetailsHtml() {
    document.getElementById('detailedContent').innerHTML = '                        <ion-item color="dark">\n' +
      '                            <ion-label class="white-text" position="stacked">Member Since</ion-label>\n' +
      '                            <ion-input id="memberSince" readonly type="text"></ion-input>\n' +
      '                        </ion-item>\n' +
      '                        <ion-item color="dark">\n' +
      '                            <ion-label class="white-text" position="stacked">Email Address</ion-label>\n' +
      '                            <ion-input id="emailAddress" readonly  type="text">{{item.email}}</ion-input>\n' +
      '                        </ion-item>\n' +
      '                        <ion-item color="dark">\n' +
      '                            <ion-label class="white-text" position="stacked">First Name</ion-label>\n' +
      '                            <ion-input id="firstName" autocapitalize="words" type="text"></ion-input>\n' +
      '                        </ion-item>\n' +
      '                        <ion-item color="dark">\n' +
      '                            <ion-label class="white-text" position="stacked">Last Name</ion-label>\n' +
      '                            <ion-input id="lastName" autocapitalize="words" type="text"></ion-input>\n' +
      '                        </ion-item>\n' +
      '      <section>\n' +
      '        <ion-button onclick="memberDetails(\'update\');presentAlert(\'Saved\', \'\');" expand="block">Save</ion-button>\n' +
      '      </section>';
  }
}
```

as seen based on the path then the HTML will be loaded. I am wondering how I can render the item object to the inputs so the values are set. Eg

```
<ion-input>{{ item.email }}</ion-input>
```

as currently if I do `{{ item.email }}` it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: You can do '<ion-input id="emailAddress" readonly  type="text">' + item.email + '</ion-input>\n'

Comment: interpolation works for binding variables in HTML templates.

Comment: That's not how you use angular. Just put that code in the template and if you need to conditionally display it, use *ngIf.

Comment: @Clashsoft I am new to anular. But this seems like the right solution for me. Thanks for the suggestion and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place all of the code in to your HTML and call it using conditions, not in your TypeScript through complex methods.

Consider using `*ngIf` ([Angular NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)) or `*ngSwitch` ([Angular NGSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch)).

An example for your scenario:

```
<div *ngIf="value == true">
 // Your HTML here
</div>
```

Or

```
<div *ngIf="value == true; else doSomethingElse">
 // Your HTML here
</div>

<ng-template #doSomethingElse>
 <div>
  // If false, display this HTML.
 </div>
</ng-template>
```